# BigQuery Load Job Limitation of 15 TB

Tags: google-bigquery

While loading large datasets into BigQuery . The table size is more than 170TB. In BigQuery we've heard that there is a limitation of not more than 15 TB of load limit per load job irrespective of file zip being Avro , parquet etc. If yes, then can you please share any workaround or options to load such high volume of data?

Answer (score 0):

Check the quotas page to find the documented limitations:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

There's a "*Maximum size per load job — 15 TB across all input files for CSV, JSON, Avro, Parquet, and ORC*" restriction indeed.

But you should be able to load 170TB easily, across multiple load jobs. Or you are telling us that all you have is a single 170TB file?

If you can use multiple load jobs from multiple files to a single table, the limit is "*Load jobs per table per day — 1,000*". That
s 2 orders of magnitude above the size the question asks about.